# Обоснование употребления родительного падежа

Tags: падежи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(учебник логики Гетмановой)

"Он открыл спутников Юпитера".

Почему падеж родительный (не винительный)?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет родительного падежа. 
Это одушевленный винительный.

Не знаю, когда был сделан сей перевод, но очевидно, что в таком переводе совершенно безосновательно отброшен важнейший контекст: слово спутник здесь означает не грамматически одушевленного попутчика, а неодушевленное небесное тело, вращающееся вокруг планеты... Поэтому форма винительного одушевленного неуместна. 
Но, повторюсь, это проблема времени перевода, поскольку "неодушевленные" значения слово "спутник" развило  только недавно, в космическую эпоху.

> ГДЕ же тут проблема времени перевода?

Проблема в том, или переводчик или редактор со сна или просто по недоразумению воспользовался старой парадигмой для одушевленных спутников. "Вижу змеи" - вам любой реактор исправит на "змеев". А если речь идет о воздушных, неодушевленных?

В любом случае это не проблема Даля. Перевод был явно сделан позже. Но и не проблема автора, поскольку он текст цитирует. Это проблема времени перевода.

Вот если бы вы нашли пример неодушевленного использования до, скажем так, Циолковского...

**UPD.**
Поскольку эта тема неожиданно для меня оказалась удостоенной внимания, потратил немного времени, чтобы убедиться в  справедливости своих выводов.

Каюсь, я погорячился с формулировкой "проблема времени перевода". Это проблема глобальнее, более протяженная во времени. И не Пойа автор первого оригинального текста, переведенного таким образом.

Вот самое раннее, что удалось найти при поверхностном поиске.

> ....попали к английскому математику Томасу Харриотту (а, может быть,
>   были конструированы им лично или кем-нибудь из его окружения), который
>   производил наблюдения солнечных пятен и спутников Юпитера почти
>   одновременно с Галилеем (с октября 1616 г.)

В. Веселовский, примечания к "Галилео Галилей. ЗВЕЗДНЫЙ ВЕСТНИК, (1610)", 1964 г.
http://www.astro-cabinet.ru/library/Galiley/Zw_vestnik.htm

> Выкинув две буквы, Кеплер получил: Salve, umblstlneum geminatum Martia
>   proles(Привет вам, близнецы, Марса порождение). Он думал, что Галилей
>   открыл  спутников Марса.

1968 г. "Знание - Сила".

Аналогичное находится в разных изданиях

> Он открыл спутников Юпитера, которых в честь своего покровителя назвал
>   "Медические звезды"

Б. Рассел, перевод, 70-х годов

И еще много где. Гугл ловит "на-ура"

Alex_andr дает в комментариях еще более ранние вхождения:

> открыл спутников Юпитера - Вестник Академии наук, 1964, 2) (Алван
>   Кларк) открыл спутника у звезды Сириуса - Физика в школе, 1957, 3)
>   открыл спутников Юпитера - Мироведение, 1935

*Я этот период даже не смотрел.*

Вывод. Старая "одушевленная" норма держалась еще долго даже после Циолковского И, похоже, что в определенном контексте была основным вариантом.

Гипотеза о "случайном" использовании родительного полностью несостоятельна.

Comment: 1. _...это проблема времени перевода, поскольку "неодушевленные" значения слово "спутник" развило только недавно, в космическую эпоху._  У Даля: Спутник, луна, меньшее небесное тело, которое ходит вкруг планеты, земли, обращаясь вместе с нею вкруг солнца. У юпитера и сатурна по нескольку лун или спутников.  (https://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=38561) Не думаю, что здесь имеются в виду одушевленные существительные. 2. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пойа,_Дьёрдь ГДЕ же тут проблема времени перевода?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова в тексте отвечу.

Comment: Зачем нам Циолковский, который умер в 1935 году? Пойа писал "глубоко" после войны — Вы не посмотрели мою вторую ссылку (1959; 1975; 1976). Переводы, естественно, ещё позже.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  *Переводы, естественно, ещё позже*.  А зачем вам в таком случае Даль? Давайте вернемся к сути. Вы почему-то не согласились  с формулировкой "проблема времени перевода", сославшись на Даля. Вместо пояснений я получаю ссылки непонятно на что. Вы хотите сказать, что это проблема автора? Или цитирующего? Не поверю. И уж конечно это никак не доказывает, что речь идет о родительном падеже.

Comment: НЕТ здесь "проблемы времени перевода". Есть обычная описка (или опечатка), потому что в других изданиях этого автора (и не только этого) цитата приводится с правильным падежом. Это Вы утверждаете одушевленность — вот и предоставьте сами хоть один пример. P. S. Я не согласна с Вашим мнением, а свое пытаюсь отстоять хотя бы при помощи ссылок. Вы же не ссылаетесь вообще ни на что. Но я ведь Вас за это "не наказываю"!

Comment: Цитируемое произведение относится к 1935 году. Искусственных спутников не было, но требует разбирательства, как именно поступали тогда в русском с астрономическими терминами. В обыденных же, не терминологических смыслах "спутники" могут _и сейчас_ одушевляться в винительном падеже, в форме "вечных спутников чего-либо". Так или иначе, вина современного автора в том, что она, зная, что имеет дело с **переводом**, не стала переводить с русского на (современный) русский.

Comment: «…мы залетели за пределы атмосферы… Теперь мы подобны Луне, потому что превратились **в спутник Земли**» (К. Э. Циолковский. «Грезы о Земле и небе и эффекты всемирного тяготения», 1895 год). При винительном одушевленном было бы _в спутника Земли._ Не было у спутников планет никакой одушевлённости.

Comment: @Alex_ander Вот ещё: _Весьма возможно, что через несколько тысяч лет и они обратятся в шар, т. е. **спутник Сатурна**_ (К. Э. Циолковский Жизнь Вселенной).

Comment: Ну, раз с астрономией всё в порядке было, то это похоже на корректорский просмотр.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  *При винительном одушевленном было бы*  - вот ві и ответили, свой на вопрос, причем здесь Циолковский. С него, точнее с его эпохи, "спутник" потерял грамматическую одушевленность. Напиши эту в фразу при Дале, было бы именно "в спутника".

Comment: @Alex_ander никто собственно и не сомневается, что это просмотр корректора (или вернее - редактора). Вопрос в том, почему врзникла сама ошибка.  считаю, что сплоховал переводчик, не посмотрев на контекст (возможно машинный перевод, в конце прошлого века эти программы были полны подобных ляпов),  РМ, насколько я её понимаю, стоит на позиции случайного грамматического ляпа,  описки, но это плохое объяснение, потому, что ничего не объяснет - уже потому, что слишком универсально.  Мне сначала даже показалось, что РМ просто не поняла сути, но она настаивает...

Comment: Все внесли свой вклад. Переводчик сплоховал + автор процитировала переводчика вместо автора, а корректор просмотрел. Началось с переводчика: он мог спросонья отвлечься от контекста и принять спутники Юпитера за спутников Зевса, корректор в спешке не прочитал этой фразы, в результате _сознательная_ ошибка - на счету автора :).

Comment: Ещё бывалый наборщик мог всех поправить: спутников Юпитера "закрыли", а Галилей их освободил (открыл).

Comment: @Alex_ander Я сейчас опровергну все ваши тезисы. Форма "открыл  спутников" употреблялась задолго до рассматриваемого издания у самых разных авторов. Подробности - в тексте  ответа.

Comment: Да, вижу такое в старых книгах: 1) открыл спутников Юпитера - Вестник Академии наук, 1964, 2) (Алван Кларк) открыл спутника у звезды Сириуса - Физика в школе, 1957, 3) открыл спутников Юпитера - Мироведение, 1935

Comment: Ох, спасибо... Я 35-й год даже не смотрел...

Comment: Первая цитата из Ваших поисков (там где "производил наблюдения спутников") не по теме — это родительный падеж.

Answer (score 0):

*Вот как описывает открытия Г. Галилея Д. Пойа: «С помощью своего только что изобретенного телеско­па он открыл **спутники** Юпитера...»*
[А. Д. Гетманова. Логика для юристов. Со сборником задач. Учебное пособие](https://books.google.ee/books?id=lVIEAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT340&lpg=PT340&dq=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%AE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%94.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=gLjUXd7iiZ&sig=ACfU3U3AeKxtniFt0XZS3C-vLQIDc-BWtA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH3ar45arjAhUawMQBHXQSABsQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%AE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%94.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B0&f=false) (**2013**)

Я думаю, что это просто опечатка (ошибка корректора), которую исправили в более позднем издании. Связать ее [ошибку] можно с тем, что в самом начале предложения говорится **об открытиях** Галилея, а здесь падеж при управлении родительный: открытие (чего?) спутников.

"Правильная" цитата есть также здесь:
[О. П. Лебедева. Логика: учеб.-метод. пособие](https://books.google.ee/books?id=8ge8qb3l-jYC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%AE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%94.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=LLNHhETm3M&sig=ACfU3U3EstLPOfdUd04499CiMu5AaBubeg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCw4DK6KrjAhXxxcQBHcquAJ8Q6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%AE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%94.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B0&f=false) (2008)

**Дополнение** (к вопросу о неодушевлённости спутников планет)

*Весьма возможно, что через несколько тысяч лет и они **обратятся в** шар, т. е. **спутник** Сатурна* ([К. Э. Циолковский. Жизнь Вселенной](https://books.google.ee/books?id=hlLSCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT45&lpg=PT45&dq=%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80,%20%D1%82.%20%D0%B5.%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=5_0mzLAMA8&sig=ACfU3U05db_9Z_7z8A028RLrYcOlrpMbjg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSxvOt5azjAhXxl4sKHcpLCkgQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%2C%20%D1%82.%20%D0%B5.%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0&f=false)).

*Да, это простой болид, но болид очень крупный, который благодаря силе притяжения Земли **превратился в ее спутник*** ([Ж. Г. Верн. Вокруг Луны](https://books.google.ee/books?id=fCB4BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=pkOeZ6cGWg&sig=ACfU3U1w_s9FXr4zwSxfzSYMC8QyFsIMtA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiztqON5azjAhVmsIsKHfUABxsQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&f=false) ).

Comment: *что в самом начале предложения говорится об открытиях Галилея, а здесь падеж при управлении родительный: открытие* - зачем за придумывать родительный падеж, когда есть простое объяснение?

Comment: *Представив себя и **своих спутников**, Коммуний Иванович спросил (а капитан перевела), есть ли у меня какие-нибудь вопросы*. (Войнович) - это какой падеж? Неужели тоже родительный?!